# Define recursive references - lazy val causes stack overflow

Tags: scala, recursion, lazy-evaluation

For a data-flow scenario I need values that recursively reference each other. The following doesn't work:

```
class Foo(val that: Foo)

class Bar {
  lazy val a: Foo = new Foo(b)
  lazy val b: Foo = new Foo(a)
  println(s"a = $a, b = $b")
}

new Bar  // boom!
```

How would I solve this without getting my hands dirty with a `var`?

Comment: How would you solve this with a `var`?

Comment: @Noah, I think he means a `var` inside `Foo`.

Comment: Yes, `class Foo(var that: Foo); val a = new Foo(null); val b = new Foo(a); a.foo = b`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need more lazy!

```
class Foo(_that: => Foo){ lazy val that = _that }


class Bar {
  lazy val a: Foo = new Foo(b)
  lazy val b: Foo = new Foo(a)
  println(s"a = $a, b = $b")
}

val bar = new Bar

bar.b.that eq bar.a
// true

bar.b eq bar.a.that
// true
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a by name parameter and another `lazy val`:

```
class Foo(_that: => Foo) {
  lazy val that = _that
}

class Bar {
  lazy val a: Foo = new Foo(b)
  lazy val b: Foo = new Foo(a)
  println(s"a = $a, b = $b")
}

val bar = new Bar()
println(bar.a.that)
```

The by name parameter defers the evaluation of the reference to the other `Foo`. Once you access `that`, both `Foo`s have been created, so you're fine.

Comment: Thanks, your and Senia's answer are identical, so sorry can only accept one.

Comment: NP. He has outrun me by a couple of seconds :)